# Sublime text: Autocompletion works when typing \\

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

I am using macOS, latest Sublime Text with package `latextools` and `latex-cwl`. It suggests commends if i type `\` and something.

However, if I type `\\` to enter new line, it suggests `\begingroup ... \endgroup`, and if I press enter, it give the command, not give `\\`. When I used Sublime Text 3 with Windows OS, I never met such suggestion.

I want to not get suggestion if I type `\\`. Is there any way to stop this suggestion?